# Jech's Set Theory, Lemma 3.10

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

[image]

I am trying to work through the proof of Lemma 3.10 in Jech's Set Theory, and can't figure out why $$ \forall \xi < \lambda: \beta_\xi < \kappa $$
According to the text the negation of the above will contradict the minimality of $\lambda$, so I tried to obtain that contradiction as follows.

If $\gamma = \min\{\xi\in \lambda: \beta_\xi = \kappa\}$, let $h$ be any bijection between $|\gamma|$ and $\gamma$. Then the family $\{ \beta_{h(\xi)}: \xi \in |\gamma|\}$ will consist of subsets of $\kappa$ of strictly smaller cardinality, while also $|\gamma| < \lambda$ .  So to get the contradiction it remains to show that $\bigcup_{\xi\in |\gamma|}\beta_{h(\xi)} = \kappa$ , and this is where I struggle. By construction, $ \bigcup_{\xi\in |\gamma|}\beta_{h(\xi)} = \bigcup_{\xi\in \gamma}\beta_{\xi} $ ,  but if I see it correctly, the original sequence $\{\beta_\xi: \xi < \lambda\}$ doesn't have to be continuous at $\gamma$.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\kappa$ is a cardinal. So by definition any well-ordered set whose cardinality is $<\kappa$, will also have that the order type is $<\kappa$. Which is exactly what Jech is using here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't see where exactly to apply this fact. Can you show it in context?

Comment: Each $S_\xi$ is a subset of $\kappa$ which is of size $<\kappa$. And $\beta_\xi$ is the order type of $S_\xi$.

Comment: $\beta_\xi$ is not the type of $S_\xi$, but of $\bigcup_{\nu<\xi}S_\nu$

Comment: Right, but the point is the same. Each union is smaller than $\kappa$.

Comment: I only know that $\forall \xi \in \lambda: S_\xi \subset \kappa \land |S_\xi|<\kappa$. How can I be sure that $|\bigcup_{\nu\in\xi}S_\xi|$ doesn't hit $\kappa$ at some $\xi$?

Comment: Oh, but that's exactly where it will contradict the minimality of $\lambda$, right?

Comment: I think I got it, thanks) It was just "on the surface" all the time

Comment: Related: http://karagila.org/2020/on-trivial-statements/

Comment: Asaf, sorry for being annoying, but I think I was too quick to conclude anything. Using your point, we get the following: if for some $\xi\in\lambda: \beta_\xi = \kappa$, then $|\bigcup_{\nu<\xi}S_\nu| = \kappa$. But it doesn't imply that $\bigcup_{\nu<\xi}S_\nu = \kappa$, so nothing contradicts the minimality of $\lambda$ yet

Comment: @Artem: Of course it does, since that means that there is a partition of $\kappa$ into $\xi$ parts. Partitions and cardinalities are invariant under bijections.